# FragmentTransaction Replace only works once

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace, fragment, fragmenttransaction

Iam working on a page where i have three buttons working like tabs, and when clicking on one of them the behavior is expected to be that the FrameLayout (Fragment container) below should replace the fragment with the expected one.

[image]

in **onCreate** of the activity i have this method, so the container shows the first fragment, (this works fine):

```
ProductDetailInformacoesFragment infoFragment = new ProductDetailInformacoesFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.product_detail_fragment_container, infoFragment);
```

Then i have a switch statement that is called on the different listeners for the buttons, so the right fragment is shown:

```
public void switchFragment(int fragmentPos)
{
    switch (fragmentPos){
        case 0:
            ProductDetailInformacoesFragment infoFragment = new ProductDetailInformacoesFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.product_detail_fragment_container, infoFragment);
            ft.commit();
            break;

        case 1:
            ProductDetailCaracteristicasFragment caracteristicasFragment = new ProductDetailCaracteristicasFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ftt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ftt.replace(R.id.product_detail_fragment_container, caracteristicasFragment);
            ftt.commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            ProductDetailAvaliacoesFragment avaliacoesFragment = new ProductDetailAvaliacoesFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fttt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fttt.replace(R.id.product_detail_fragment_container, avaliacoesFragment);
            fttt.commit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_detail_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/base_view"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

**The problem is** when i click on one of the tabs, the fragment container become blank (white) and the desired fragment is not showed, no matter which one i click (even the one that is already shown). **What am i doing wrong??** - i have tried setting ft.addToBackStack(null) didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

.You should control if your frament is null before to instanciate and add it to the container. if your fragment is instanciated you should simply show it. if a button is clicked manage to show the desired fragment using trick mentioned above, and then hide the other fragments.
You should use ActionBar feature of android. and use Tab instead of your button. onTabSelected() onTabUnselected() to respectively manage operations on your Tab like attach or detach Fragments. everything is detailled in the android developper forum. Here is the URL http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html so go to the section "Adding Navigation Tabs" for full explanation an example.

here is the overview of code for managing selection and unselection of your tabs using AndroidSupport

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fT) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case your_tab_position:
        if(your_fragment == null){
            your_fragment = new Your_fragment();
            ft.add(R.id.your_container, your_fragment, your_tag);
        }
        else{
            ft.show(your_fragment);
            }

        break;
.
.
.
}
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fT) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case your_tab_position:
        if(your_fragment != null){
            ft.hide(your_fragment);
        }
        break;
.
.
.
}
}
```